# Cosmos DB SQL API: Filter for documents with an empty nested object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What is the easiest way to query for documents having an empty nested object in Azure Cosmos DB.

The document may look like that:

```
{
    "id": "20352853!2019-06-18T12:45:00.0000000+00:00!1.5.0",
    "TimeStampUtc": "2019-06-18T12:45:00+00:00",
    "MeterId": "20352853",
    "Identifier": "1.5.0",
    "Value": 0.01,
    "State": "00",
    "Unit": "kW",
    "Properties": {},
    "_rid": "1+xXAPJv6UMBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/1+xXAA==/colls/1+xXAPJv6UM=/docs/1+xXAPJv6UMBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-2b58-5ee6a4c001d5\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1561468662
}
```

I am looking for documents with a nested empty `Properties` object like in the sample.

Comment: just to clarify, you are using sql api, right?

Comment: @4c74356b41: yes, I use the SQL API

Answer (score 2):

the following seem to work for me:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.Properties != {}
```

that is if you are using SQL API just like your tags suggest

Comment: I was looking for documents having an empty nested property object. ```SELECT * FROM c where c.Properties != {}``` filters for ```c.Properties NOT EQUAL {}```. If I execute that function I get an empty result set. Trying to filter for ```SELECT * FROM c where c.Properties == {}``` results in an syntax error ```"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '='.```